# Is DMS content relevant when using extract?

Tags: boil, extract, dms

Most extract kits suggest simply dropping the extract in the bucket with some boiling water.  Do extract brewers need to be concerned about DMS levels or is that taken care of in the starch conversion process during "extraction"?

From a purely DMS point-of-view, is it worth doing a partial poil when using extract?  Would a pilsner / light pale extract need to go through the 90 minute boil process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Brew Strong episode about DMS](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/485) they said that pilsner extract did not need a longer boil, since the DMS would be off gassed during the process of concentrating the extract.